# CSS and JavaScript not working in Android WebView

Tags: android, jquery, css, webview, android-webview

My **MainActivity.java** file looks like below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String myUrl = "file:///android_asset/index.html";
        WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        view.loadUrl(myUrl);
    }
}
```

Now, **activity_main.xml** file contains following codes:

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And, in the html page **index.html**, I have been linking CSS and JS files like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="file:///android_asset/js/popper.min.js"></script>
```

I am seeing the html content; but, the CSS and JavaScript files are not in action at all. The page looks plain. I am new to Android, I am certainly missing something crucial here.

Comment: I'm not sure if WebView can pick up `file:///android_asset/*` css and js files. You can try using CDN links of both. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#download-cdn and https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react-popper

Comment: Thank you, it worked as I restarted the computer and re-launched Android Studio/emulator.

Answer (score 2):

In the `html` page `index.html`, use the path names ***relative*** to your `html` page (not **`file:///android_asset`**).

So change this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="file:///android_asset/js/popper.min.js"></script>
```

To this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
```

with directory structure:

```
+---assets
¦   +---css
¦   +---js
```